# Error when generating a doctrine 2 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have already created entities initiall on my projects creationy and now have a table i would like to automap a single entity for.

i ran: `php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/MyBundle/Resources/config --from-database --filter="clicks"`

and get:

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

I am looking to just generate the entity of that one table "clicks"

Can anyone explain to me why this might be happening and how I can get this command to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you've successfully use this command to generate entities before, it should normally work.

You can get this error, when the table does not actually exist in the database.

Double check if the table "clicks" is in the database.

Comment: It definitely exists. Could there be something wrong with how im specifying the filter?

Comment: Nothing wrong with filter. Is the table name all lowercase in the database ?